# React Grid Layout resets the layout when new item is added

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I am using React Grid Layout. I followed the demo to create a simple layout. I wanted to add new items to the grid. However, if I resize any item and then add a new panel, the layout resets. I am not sure what is causing the layout to reset.

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-sammet-8vi44n?file=/src/ShowcaseLayout.js

Comment: facing same problem. what is found out is when we add new item, prevState is having x, y (0,0) .. means upon dragging or resizing, state is not changing. did you find out any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The core logic revolves around two pieces of state: gridItems for storing information about the grid items, and layout for tracking their layout (position and size). When a new item is added by clicking a button, it is appended to both gridItems and layout states. The addItem function calculates the position and dimensions for the new item, setting it to appear at the bottom of the grid. The onLayoutChange callback, triggered whenever an item is resized or moved, updates the layout state to reflect these changes. This ensures that any adjustments made by the user to the item positions or sizes are retained, providing a consistent and interactive grid layout experience.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Responsive, WidthProvider } from 'react-grid-layout';
import 'react-grid-layout/css/styles.css';
import 'react-resizable/css/styles.css';

const ResponsiveGridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive);

function MyGridLayout() {
  const [gridItems, setGridItems] = useState([]);
  const [layout, setLayout] = useState([]);

  const addItem = () => {
    const newKey = `item${gridItems.length}`;
    const newItem = {
      x: 0,
      y: Infinity, // Place at the bottom
      w: 2, // Width of the grid item
      h: 2, // Height of the grid item
      i: newKey, // Unique key
    };

    setGridItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, newItem]);
    setLayout(prevLayout => [...prevLayout, newItem]);
  };

  const onLayoutChange = useCallback((newLayout) => {
    setLayout(newLayout);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addItem}>Add Item</button>
      <ResponsiveGridLayout
        className="layout"
        layouts={{ lg: layout }}
        onLayoutChange={onLayoutChange}
        breakpoints={{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 }}
        cols={{ lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }}
        margin={[10, 10]}
      >
        {gridItems.map(item => (
          <div key={item.i}>
            <span className="text">Item {item.i}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ResponsiveGridLayout>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyGridLayout;
```